# How to genrate BKS keystore for android application in android studio

Tags: android, keystore

This is my code in main file:
can you tell me How to genrate BKS keystore for android application in android studio

```
 OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    try {
        KeyStore ksTrust = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        InputStream instream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
        ksTrust.load(instream, "secret".toCharArray());

        // TrustManager decides which certificate authorities to use.
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ksTrust);
         sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyManagementException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"in catch");
        Log.e(TAG,e.toString());

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: not BKS it .JKS

Comment: But I have to Create BKS file for SSL Certificate..

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to create bks cert.

keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "path_to_cert/interm_ca.cer" -alias IntermediateCA -keystore "res/raw/myKeystore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "path_to_bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16-145.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mysecret

Details are here,

http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/

Comment: AFAIK this command will only work today if you use the specified old version of BouncyCastle. With newer versions it will not work because the `BKS` implementation of BouncyCastle has changed. Today you need to use the storetype `BKS-v1` instead.

Comment: Then what is the solution @Robert

Comment: @prem nath use the latest BouncyCastle version instead, change `storetype` and `providerpath` arguments as I described.

Comment: How to create this file "path_to_cert/interm_ca.cer" @Robert

Comment: This is the file which is on your sever.Its a certified file.

Comment: @prem nath Trusted certificates are root, intermediate or server ceruficates. For SSL/TLS certificates just open the site in your web browser, open the certificate info dialog and save e.g. the root certificate to a `.cer` or `.der` file.